# FileNotFoundException when reading .xml file to parse

Tags: java, xml-parsing, filenotfoundexception

I'm writing a program in Java where I read in data from an XML file and parse it. The file is imported into a folder named "Resources" in the src directory of my project. I'm using Eclipse. When I run the program, I get the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/thechiman/Dropbox/introcs/PSU SOC Crawler/resources/majors_xml_db.xml (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:66)
...
```

The relevant code is here:

```
private void parseXML() {
    //Get a factory
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    try {
        //Use factory to get a new DocumentBuilder
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        //Parse the XML file, get DOM representation
        dom = db.parse("resources/majors_xml_db.xml");
    } catch(ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();
    } catch(SAXException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I do not understand why I'm getting the FileNotFoundException when the file is there. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This may not be an issue, but thought I'd note that in your description you've called the folder "Resources" and in the code it's "resources". On an operating system with case-sensitive paths, this could cause a problem.

Comment: The capitalization was a typo. it's "resources" in both places.

Comment: Have you tried using this instruction?
System.getProperty("user.dir")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With [`DocumentBuilder.parse(String)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29), the argument is interpreted as a URI, and in this case, it's going to be a relative URI (the string you're giving it is not a "full" URI). What it's relative *to* is a bit ambiguous at this point, without further information on your setup. The runtime will be interpreting it as relative to *something*, but it's not clear here what that something is.

You'll get more reliable results by using one of the other `parse` methods, such as [`parse(File)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse%28java.io.File%29) or [`parse(InputStream)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse%28java.io.InputStream%29). In each case, there's no ambiguity as to what you're asking it to parse.

If you decide to construct a `File` object first (to pass to `parse` later), then you have a more manageable problem of making sure that that file exists (using `File.exists()` and so on). If you can't get that far, then your problem isn't with `DocumentBuilder` or the DOM, it's with basic file paths. Remember that if you use relative file paths (e.g. `new File("resources/majors_xml_db.xml")`) then this will be resolved relative to the working directory of the process. If it works or not depends on how you launch your program.

Comment: I tried making a File object using <code>File f = new File("resources/majors_xml_db.xml"</code>. However, I run into the same problem as before. I guess what I don't understand is how to properly format the URI string.

My file is located at a directory on my MacBook Pro: /Users/thechiman/Dropbox/introcs/PSU SOC Crawler/resources/majors_xml_db.xml

In Eclipse, I created a directory "resources" under the "src" directory of my project. I placed the "majors_xml_db.xml" file in the "resources" file.

I don't understand how to create a file. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I switched to PC machine and tried compiling the program there. I replaced the file path string with "C:/Users/Eric So/My Dropbox/introcs/PSU SOC Crawler/src/resources/majors_xml_db.xml" and it worked! This, however is tied to my local file structure. I put the file into Eclipse. Is there any way to make it find the file using the relative file path "resources/majors_xml_db.xml"? Thanks.

Comment: @thechiman: Yes, you need to execute the program with `C:/Users/Eric So/My Dropbox/introcs/PSU SOC Crawler/src` as the working directory.